# jQuery object descendant filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Assuming I have a tree structure

```
UL
--LI
---INPUT (checkbox)
```

And I want to grab the checked inputs, I would select

```
$('ul li input:checked')
```

However, I want to select the checked inputs of a specific object $myUL that doesn't have an ID.

```
$myUL.children('li input:checked')
```

returns all li's since children filters immediate children - the checked filter has no impact.

Is there another way around this? Another descendant filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$myUL.find('li>input:checked')`

Answer (score 0):

`$myUL.find('li>input:checked')` work as expected. Any trade off of performance?